# Non-symmetric matrix with orthogonal eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Given that a symmetric matrix with real entries has orthogonal eigenvectors, is the converse true? That is, if a matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors, does it have to be symmetrical and real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a matrix $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors, then there exists an orthogonal $P$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ such that 
$$
A=P\Lambda P^\top
$$
It follows that 
$$
A^\top
= (P\Lambda P^\top)^\top
= (P^\top)^\top\Lambda^\top P^\top=P\Lambda P^\top=A
$$
Hence $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: So, why the eigenvalues are necessarily real?

Comment: @AndreasH. I thought that was in OP's original assumptions.

Comment: He only mentioned orthogonality of eigenvectors, though I presume he might have also assumed that the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: This answer is incorrect according to the OP's requirements

Answer (score 5):

Answer to the question (v1): *No,* consider e.g. the anti-Hermitian matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which has eigenvalues $\pm i$, and which is (complex) orthogonal diagonalizable$^{\dagger}$.

---

$^{\dagger}$ Note that the underlying [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) is implicitly assumed to be a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) rather than a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form).

Answer (score 3):

If you allow your matrix to have complex eigenvalues/eigenvectors, the answer is no. However, you can say something about that matrix, namely that is *normal*.

**Definition:** a matrix $A$ is said to be normal if $A^HA=AA^H$, where $A^H$ denotes the transpose and conjugate matrix of $A$.

The spectral theorem says that being normal and being unitarily diagonalizable are equivalent statements.

Now, if you restrict your attention to matrices with *real* eigenvalues and *real* orthogonal eigenvectors that form a complete basis, then your statement is true, as Brian showed you. This is because $A^{\top}=A^H$ for real matrices.